# Java Graph Path Backtracking

Tags: java, graph, backtracking

Hi there I have a problem and again I am stuck.

I have a directed Vertex weighted graph and I need to find a shortest possible path.

The weight on verticies can be both positive and negative.
There are the rules:

- You can start at any vertex
- You can step on any vertex more then one time
- You don't need to visit all verticies
- If there is not negative solution (there doesn't exist path with negative cost) the graph has no solution
- There are cycles
- There are verticies with degree 1 (both in and out)
- Every strong component is conected to the graph

And a time-limit is 60ms for '|V(G)| ~ 1000, |E(G)| ~ 500000'

And yes its a work assigment and I am stuck after 192hours of work, tried every possible thing and nothing works...

Thank you for any advice, JC

Comment: Looked into modifying A*? (having only used graphs for games this is what I am most familiar with, sounds like it should be appliable)

Comment: @arynaq Yes I have tried A* but its even slower than Dijkstra and it doesn't solve (or I didn't find a way to solve) the problem with "visiting cycles on the way if they add negative cost to overall path"

for example I will write a simple graph VERTEX[COST]

1[0] -- 2[-5] -- 5[-10] -- 7[5] -- 5[-5] -- 9[-2]

The path I would like is 2-5-7-5-9 but what I get is 1-2-5-9